# About Linux NMI watchdog

Tags: linux, performancecounter, watchdog, apic

Now I encounter a problem about Linux NMI Watchdog.
I want to use Linux NMI watchdog to detect and recovery OS hang. So, I add "nmi_watchdog=1" into grub.cfg. And then check the */proc/interrupt*, NMI were triggered per second. But after I load a module with deadlock (double-acquire spinlock), system were hanged totally, and nothing occurs (never panic!). It looks like that NMI watchdog did not work!

Then I read the Documentation/nmi_watchdog.txt, it says:

> Be aware that when using local APIC, the frequency of NMI interrupts
> it generates, depends on the system load. The local APIC NMI watchdog,
> lacking a better source, uses the "**cycles unhalted**" event.

What's the "**cycles unhalted**" event?

It added:

> but if your system locks up on anything but the "hlt" processor
> instruction, the watchdog will trigger very soon as the "cycles
> unhalted" event will happen every clock tick...If it locks up on
> "hlt", then you are out of luck -- the event will not happen at all
> and the watchdog **won't** trigger.

Seems like that watchdog won't trigger if processor executes "hlt" instruction, then I search "hlt" in "*Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual, Volumn 2A*", it describes it as follow:

> Stops instruction execution and places the processor in a HALT state.
> An enabled  interrupt (including NMI and SMI), a debug exception, the
> BINIT# signal, the INIT#  signal, or the RESET# signal will **resume**
> execution.

Then I am lost...

My question is:

- **How** does Linux NMI watchdog work?
- **Who** trigger the NMI?

My OS is Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, Linux-2.6.32.21, CPU Pentium 4 Dual-core 3.20 GHz.

I didn't read the whole source code about NMI watchdog(no time), if I couldn't understand how NMI watchdog work, I want use *performance monitoring counter interrupt* and *inter-processor interrupt* (be provided by APIC) to send NMI instead of NMI watchdog.

Comment: nice stuff NMI watchdog, add this to my tools of trade

Comment: Linux kernel implementation watchdog_nmi_enable().

Answer (score 9):

The answer depends on your hardware.

Non-maskable interrupts (NMI) can be triggered 2 ways: 1) when the kernel reaches a halting state that can't be interrupted by another method, and 2) by hardware -- using an NMI button.

On the front of some Dell servers, for example, you will see a small circle with a zig-zag line inside it. This is the NMI symbol. Nearby there is a hole. Insert a pin to trigger the interrupt. If your kernel is built to support it, this will dump a kernel panic trace to the console, then reboot the system.

This can happen very fast. So if you don't have a console attached to save the output to a file, it might look like only a reboot.

Answer (score 3):

As I know, nmi_watchdog would only triggered for *non-interruptible* hangs. I found an code example by google: http://oslearn.blogspot.in/2011/04/use-nmi-watchdog.html

If your deadlock is not non-interruptiable, you can try enable sysRq to trigger some trace (Alt-printscreen-t) or crash (Alt-printscreen-c) to get more information.

Comment: Thanks. I read the all sources about nmi_watchdog (in linux-2.6.32) already, and now I know how it work :)

Comment: The code from the original link was [reposted on kernelnewbies](https://lists.kernelnewbies.org/pipermail/kernelnewbies/2011-June/002122.html). It only works on uniprocessor systems. A [reply](https://lists.kernelnewbies.org/pipermail/kernelnewbies/2011-June/002129.html) in that thread includes code that works on multicore and SMP systems.

Comment: The blog behind the link is non public (anymore) "This blog is open to invited readers only"