# what is the relation between BIOS and the benchmark instruction pair `CPUID` and `RDTSC/RDTSCP`?

Tags: serialization, x86, benchmarking, bios

Recently when I read [ia-32-ia-64-benchmark-code-execution-paper](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/ia-32-ia-64-benchmark-code-execution-paper.pdf), it says what to do if the Section 3.2.2 method fails.

> Analyze the variance of the variances and the **variance** of the minimum values
> to validate the method on his platform. If the values that the user obtains are
> **not satisfactory**, he may have to **change the BIOS settings or the BIOS itself**.

I understand the `CPUID` after `RDTSCP` can make the subsequent instructions not reordered before `RDTSCP`, then causing **more determined** results each time it benchmarks. The `CPUID` serializing instruction property is shown in [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual Volume 3A 9.3 SERIALIZING INSTRUCTIONS](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/intel-sdm.html)

> **Nothing can pass** a serializing
> instruction and a serializing instruction **cannot pass** any other instruction (read, write, instruction fetch, or I/O).

---

After viewing this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8602589/21294350), BIOS controls the resets of the TSC, but how does it influence the variance of multiple iteration results?

Q:

what is the relation between BIOS and the benchmark instruction pair (i.e. `CPUID` and `RDTSC/RDTSCP`) except for the TSC reset and how to check the BIOS specific errors if the Section 3.2.2 method fails?

Comment: `cpuid;rdtsc` isn't directly affected by the BIOS, AFAIK.  But the interval you're timing might be if the BIOS uses SMIs (System Management Interrupts, into System Management Mode, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_Mode).  That might be what Intel is talking about.  Good motherboards with good BIOSes don't run any SMIs on a timer, or at all after fully booted; under Linux you can use `turbostat` or `perf` to count SMIs, or `rdmsr`: [Evaluating SMI (System Management Interrupt) latency on Linux-CentOS/Intel machine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25399405)

Comment: [Evaluating SMI (System Management Interrupt) latency on Linux-CentOS/Intel machine](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/122675137) mentions `sudo rdmsr -d 0x34` to read the total since-boot SMI count.  And points out that if it's still going up over time, the system might not be suitable for hard-realtime uses.  Which is a pretty similar criterion to low-variance timing for the some work with interrupts disabled.  Oh, NMIs are also possible, although usually only for faults like ECC memory; BIOS might allow disabling the reporting.

Comment: 1. Thanks for your always in-time help. With my amd zen2 17h family cpu r7 4800h, I use `perf stat -a -A -e r02B -- sleep 2` by following https://stackoverflow.com/a/73548419/21294350 and SMI is indeed disabled as you have said. Also `turbostat` has no `SMI` column. 2. The NMI can be disabled in the kernel cfg by `nmi_watchdog=0` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865952), is it that case?